# How to model a bending straw in JavaFX

Tags: user-interface, javafx, shapes

My goal is to make it so that when a user slides a Slider, an object that is like a straw bends from its middle.

Sort of like this:
http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/bendy-straw-a-1.jpg

I've spent days searching for ways to model this with JavaFX shapes, but maybe I'm missing something obvious. When the Slider is at zero, the shape should be a straight line, whereas when the Slider is bent all the way, the shape should resemble an arm of a hyperbola.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I would use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CubicCurve.html .  I hope you don't want all those bumps in the line, that would be hard

Comment: I've looked through all of the documentation on their API, the problem is just where to set the control points? And no, the bumps are not needed

Comment: Sorry I meant QuadQurve, and you'll have to move both the control and end points when the slider moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to figure out the math correctly, but something like this is what I had in mind.  You can even try just leaving the control point Y in the middle of the line, I moved it up since I figured it's more realistic, like it will start to bend at the bottom.  You also have to do some calculus to figure out the end point.  The length shouldn't change.

```
package curve;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurve;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Curve extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        QuadCurve qc = new QuadCurve(100, 500, 100, 250, 100, 0);
        qc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        qc.setStrokeWidth(5);
        qc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 200, 0);
        qc.endXProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().add(100));
        qc.endYProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().add(100).divide(1.2));
        qc.controlYProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().multiply(-1).add(500));

        Group group = new Group(qc,slider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 500,500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```